# typescript error on tsyringe delay function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsyringe

I'm trying to inject some dependency with tsyringe delay function but the typescript are warning me with the follow error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'constructor<any>'.ts(2322)
lazy-helpers.d.ts(9, 54): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

I need this delay because TypeORM take some time to establish a connection with the database, and if my injection refers to an Database provider, it throw an Exception case the TypeORM don't establish the connection yet.

The code below works, but i thought that is something wrong as typescript is given me the error message, there is a way to resolve that?

Code sample

```
import { delay, inject, injectable } from "tsyringe";
import { IRandomProvider } from "@shared/container/providers/IRandomProvider";

@injectable()
class RandomClass {
    constructor(
        @inject(delay(() => "RandomProvider"))
        private randomProvider: IRandomProvider
    ) {}
```

Tsyringe delay helper function doc: https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#the-delay-helper-function

tsyringe version: 4.6.0